# Fortran scientific notation 1d0 vs 1.d0

Tags: fortran, ieee-754, scientific-notation

Does it make any difference to declare a double precision variable as

```
double precision :: var1, var2, var3
    
var1 = 1d0
var2 = 1.d0
var3 = 1.0d0
```

I believe `var2` and `var3` are identical. Are there any errors that may appear if we do not include the dot in the declaration (as in `var1`)?

Comment: The best is to avoid double precision notation and suffix numbers with the appropriate kind, like: `use iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64; real(RK) :: a = 1._RK`. This way, you will be able to change the kinds whenever needed in the future. The presence of the decimal dot `.` improves readability to easily distinguish it from integers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no differences between `1d0`, `1.d0` and  `1.0d0` whatsoever. They represent the same literal value with the same type.

Be aware that for this specific small integer value you can get away with just using the default kind value `1.0` and you can definitely use the integer value `1`.